# Would two identical universes evolve identically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, determinism, chaos-theory

What if there were 2 universes (completely disconnected - not part of the same multiverse) which were identical and a given point in time (say when they first began). Would these 2 universes evolve in exactly the same way?

My understanding of quantum uncertainty would lead me to be believe they would not evolve in the same way (in other words, reality is inherently non-deterministic), but I'd like to hear what others think. Also, just to check my understanding, if we say the universe were indeed "deterministic", the 2 universes would always evolve the same, correct?

Comment: There can be no "two universes" by definition of the word "universe" to begin with. This is a typical case of a grammatically correct question that does not have a semantic meaning.

Comment: This is a purely hypothetical question to understand the nature of quantum mechanics.

Comment: So it's a purely hypothetical question without meaning. OK.

Comment: @CuriousOne It's a hypothetical question - a thought experiment - for the purpose stated: "to understand the nature of quantum mechanics". By the way, your original comment about there being no semantic meaning to "two universes" is completely at odds with the idea of a "multiverse"...

Answer (score -1):

Due to the Uncertainty principle, the matter in a **closed** universe can only inhabit a certain number of positions (a really big number though). This means that although it is unlikely that two independent universes would evolve exactly the same, it is possible, and if there are infinite universes then two universes must be the same. Sorry for the brief answer, I have limited time. I suggest reading the book "The Hidden Reality" by Brian Greene for a more complete answer to your question.

Comment: I see that it is possible that there would be 2 universes which could evolve the same... I should have worded my question as "will they ALWAYS evolve the same".